# iOS - Unexpected VoiceOver behavior on customized UIPickerView

Tags: ios, accessibility, uipickerview

I have a somewhat customized UIPickerView in my app. Basically I use `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView` returning a simple UILabel. As I started working on making the app more accessible, I noticed that VoiceOver reads label and adds, say, "3 of 300" (i.e. row number "of" total rows). This is not a desired behavior.

While trying to troubleshoot this, I found that if I use `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent` instead of `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView`, without any other changes, then I get the desired behavior of VoiceOver simply reading the "title" of the selected row. I tested this on iOS 9.

Question is: how do I get UIPickerView back to the "normal" VoiceOver behavior, while still using `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView`? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try setting some of the `UIAccessibilityElement` properties on the label. Some combination may help.

Comment: You should also read over [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790992/how-to-set-the-voice-over-accessibility-label-for-uipickerview-rows).

Comment: @rmaddy I tried to set basically all accessibility properties on that label, but to no avail.. If you think about it, the label itself is not even aware of its own row number or especially total row count.. So logically this is probably some property of the picker itself.

Comment: See the link I added. Using the `UIPickerViewAccessibilityDelegate` will probably help.

Comment: @rmaddy I actually read that post before asking my question. `UIPickerViewAccessibilityDelegate` has only two functions, assigning a label and a hint to a given "component" (i.e. wheel) of the picker. I even use it in my app already. It has no control over speaking the row number for each selected row, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

I asked Apple support for help on this. The official reply was: "Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations". (For posterity - this was when the newest iOS version was 9.4). They suggested to file a request for new functionality, which I may do.

To solve this problem I went with the following workaround.

- Created a base class almost identical to the class I had, but implementing only `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent` and not `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView`. This class presents vanilla non-customized picker.
- Created a subclass of that base class, now implementing `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView`. This class presents a fully customized picker.
- In my code elsewhere used `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` to create an object of base class when VoiceOver is on, and an object of the subclass otherwise

Thus when a user is running VoiceOver, they get a visually ugly picker, but one that is perfectly well-behaved in terms of accessibility (i.e. no row number announcements). Which is a perfectly reasonable "compromise" I think, since the user is basically guaranteed not to care about the visual appearances.

Answer (score 0):

One fix will be to check if voice over is running

```
UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
```

If so use `titleForRow` otherwise use `viewForRow`.  That way you don't degrade normal experience.

Comment: If you look at my own solution, that is basically what I did. As I understand, iOS uses introspection to check if delegate implements `viewForRow`, and if so then uses that method rather than `titleForRow`. Due to this introspection I had to subclass. But perhaps you can suggest a way to prevent iOS from using `viewForRow` without subclassing?